# Assigning values to list in python

Tags: python-2.7

```
while (i<r && j<u) { 
    if (a[i]<=a[j]) {
      b[k]=a[i]; 
      i++;
    } 
    else {
      b[k]=a[j];
      j++;
    }
    k++;
}
```

In the above C++ code values of two arrays is checked and value of one array is assigned to another array when the depending upon the condition satisfies.

am beginner programmer in python.There is something called list in python similar to array in c++. how the above code can be implemented in python?

Comment: Out of interest, what is this code doing? This algorithm looks vaguely familiar...

Comment: am trying to implement merge sort in iterative version

Comment: then the pythonic way is to do `list(sorted(a))`. but if you insist on implementing merge, use can drop the `k` variable and use `b.append(min(a[i], a[j]))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a list construct baked right into the core of Python, below is a pretty good introduction:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm

You could re-write the code above pretty much identically in python, just changing the syntax from C++ to python. However, there may be a more *pythonic* way of doing what you require, it is hard to say without having more context around the code.

```
while i < r and j < u:
    if a[i] <= a[j]:
        b[k] = a[i]
        i += 1               # No increment operator in python
    else:
        b[k] = a[j]
        j += 1
    k += 1
```